# XDocument not loading File using Tasks

Tags: linq-to-xml, task

I have this piece of code which I wrote to load am XML file using the XDocument.Parse
Method. I basically need to read the XML file at a regular interval of say 5 Seconds.

The problem is that code "XDocument.Parse(res.Result)" and anything after that is not getting executed, ie the application just finishes execution without processing this code.

However, If I place the same code outside the Task Methods then it works fine. I have tried using XDocument.Load method and also use a Timer but I face the same problem.

```
  public void starttest()
    {

        string FilePath = @"C:\Users\maxpayne\Documents\JobSchedule.xml";
        Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>LoadFile(FilePath)).ContinueWith((res)=>{
            //
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(res.Result);
            Console.Write(res.Result);


            ProcessJob(LoadJob(doc));
            UpdateJobs();

            Sleep(5000);
        }); ;

    }
```

Comment: Simplify the code: XDocument.Load(filePath). Then you are not splitting something that really doesn't need to be split.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the load/parse into one to remove the unnecessary continuation.

```
public void starttest()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load((string)state);
        ProcessJob(LoadJob(doc));
        UpdateJobs();
    }, @"C:\Users\maxpayne\Documents\JobSchedule.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the file is being loaded on another thread, but you are not waiting for that task to complete. When `ContinueWith` returns, the task has been started, but may not have completed yet.

```
Task<string>.Factory
            .StartNew(() => LoadFile(FilePath))
            .ContinueWith((res) => 
                          {
                              XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(res.Result);
                              Console.Write(res.Result);

                              ProcessJob(LoadJob(doc));
                              UpdateJobs();

                              Sleep(5000);
                          })
           .Wait();
```

Of course, if you are synchronously waiting for the Task to complete (which this is), not only are you not faster or doing anything in parallel, you are also wasting resources doing so, because you're using two threads for this operation.